# Advantages and limitations of Gwet’s AC1 statistic and PABAK

Tags: agreement-statistics

I am looking for alternatives to the kappa to assess inter-rater agreement.  I've come across two hopefulls: Gwet’s AC1 statistic and  PABAK.  I wondered what the advantages and disadvantages of each were?

Comment: I have merged your too accounts, michelle. Please, register it; this way you will be able to edit your question, get system-wide notification, etc.

Comment: It would be good if you could add some details about your study or what you intend to measure.

Answer (score 1):

The article below compared them. PABAK is a member of the S family.

Factors affecting intercoder reliability: a Monte Carlo experiment
Author: Feng, Guangchao Charles
Journal: Quality & quantity
ISSN: 0033-5177
Date: 09/2012
DOI: 10.1007/s11135-012-9745-9

Comment: Welcome to the site. Short answers like this are usually comments rather than answers.